# Viewport Meta tag not working - Responsive Site

Tags: html, responsive, viewport

I've created a responsive website and when I resize the browser window, the site responds the way it should. However, when I check the site in my cellphone, the responsiveness doesn't work.  I've read other similar posts that were able to solve this issue by adding the viewport meta tag; and I've added it as well and nothing happens.  I've even tried building the entire site again, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

[Here is a link to the site](http://www.devcore.tech/vpaytest/index.html)

This is what my viewport tag looks like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

as you already wrote i check your code and this line of code is missing make sure that you add it in the head and save and upload your `index.html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Adel. Thanks for your comment. Apparently there is something weird with the server. Our IT person has made some changes, so I'll try it later. I hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Paula you are welcome I am sure after adding this line of code it will work fine 100% maybe it’s cache or maybe the updated page not uploaded yet but make sure that it’s updated and all will be fine